# Multiple select on mobile device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I don't know if it's a problem or it's normal. I made a multiple select form using bootstrap. The mobile version in console is displaying the informations correctly (screen1), but in a real device I get just 0 items, when I select an items it shows 1 item.... (screen2). Can someone help me to do the same as the first screen ?

[image: Screen1]

[image: Screen2]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code?

Comment: <select  class="custom-select" multiple>
                                    <option value="1">Finance and governance</option>
                                    <option value="2">Corporate Social Responsibility</option></select>

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample that can solve your issue. You need to add the multiple attribute to your `<select>` element.

[Bootstrap form documentations](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#form-controls)

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="selectList"> 
<option>Your option 1</option> 
<option>Your option 2</option> 
<option>Your option 3</option> 
<option>Your option 4</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, in the mobile device it shows me the same as the second screen